# Как обернуть выделенный код в скобки в Visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Иногда нужно выделить кусок кода в скобки. Есть ли для этого какое-то сочетание клавиш?

Comment: На выделенный кусок сочетание клавиш `Shift + {` ? У меня работает, но студия 15

Comment: @Artem.rtv в 19, к сожалению, не работает. Просто заменяет выделенный блок на символ скобки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Visual studio 2022 появилась эта функция

Нажимаем `"Средства->Параметры->Текстовый редактор->С/С++->Дополнительно"`.

В самом низу будут 2 настройки:

1. "Включение заключения в фигурные скобки"
2. "Включение заключения в круглые скобки".

Ставим в `True`

[image: VS2022]

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, словами (нажав [edit]), и оставив картинку как дополнительную информацию.